# Given a textarea generated from asp:textbox, the inner text cannot be 'set' with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a single asp:textbox declared as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" class="myTB" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True" Height="175px" 
Width="725px" BorderColor="#76B900" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" 
Style="overflow: hidden; margin: 5px;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Rendered it looks like this:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$MainContent$MainContent$textBox1" 
class="myTB" 
id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_AllContent_MainContent_MainContent_textBox1" 
style="border-bottom: #76b900 2px solid; border-left: #76b900 2px solid; 
margin: 5px; width: 725px; font-family: Calibri; height: 175px; 
font-size: small; overflow: hidden; border-top: #76b900 2px solid; 
font-weight: bold; border-right: #76b900 2px solid;" 
rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

I have tried the following JQuery and JS respectively and in either case, the content of the text-area never changes even though the value does when I look at it with the debugger

```
function generateQuery() {
    var textBox = $(".myTB");
    textBox.value = "jquery woohoo";
}
```

AND

```
function _generateQuery() {
    var textBox = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    textBox.value =" work for crying out loud ";
                }
```

And yes, it's the only textbox of that class on my page.

Comment: Did you accidentally leave out the closing tag for the textrea during the copy/paste to the question or did it not render?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
var textBox = $(".myTB");
textbox.val("jquery woohoo");
```

Comment: $(".myTB").val("Jquery woohoo"); 
looks cleaner, especially if you're not doing anything with the textbox object after that :)

Comment: @shanabus - go chaining in jQuery

Comment: The reason it didn't work with POJ (plain ole javascript) is because of the reason nickyt described.  You're returning an array of textarea elements (getElementsByName) and not indexing before setting the value.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this won't work

```
function _generateQuery() {
        var textBox = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
        textBox.value =" work for crying out loud ";
}
```

document.getElementsByTagName returns an array of elements, so if anything this would look something like this:

```
function _generateQuery() {
        var textBox = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
        textBox.value =" work for crying out loud ";
}
```

Anyways this isn't the best way to get a reference to a textarea. Use the jQuery way or pass the clientID of your textbox to your method so you can get the reference to the textarea via the ASP.NET generated element ID.